# How to select google docs ocr language?

Tags: ocr, google-docs-api

Google docs api provides [OCR service](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-docs-ocr.html).

During manual upload i can specify document language (required to ocr non-English documents),
but i don't see such option in api reference/examples.

Am i missing something or this feature is missing?

Answer (score -1):

According to the docs you can use the '''ocr-language''' parameter...

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#OCR